# D9024 make unrecognized source file type

Tags: windows, visual-studio, makefile, mingw

If I run this cmd on cmd line using MS cl:

```
cl -c /W3 /Od ioapi.c
```

the object file, ioapi.obj is created as expected.

If however I create a makefile with this entry:

```
ioapi.obj: ioapi.c
    cl -c /W3 /Od ioapi.c
```

There is a tab before cl above

and run make ioapi.obj then I get this error:

```
make ioapi.obj
cl -c /W3 /Od ioapi.c
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.21022.08 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/W3', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/W3' ignored
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/Od', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/Od' ignored
```

ioapi.c

```
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/W3', object file assumed
```

cl is the MS VS 2008 compiler.

I have installed minGW, version is from 6 months ago.

If I run make -n ioapi.c I get this reported as expected:

```
cl -c /W3 /Od ioapi.c
```

I am running cl.exe from the Visual Studio 2008 command prompt (where the VS2008 env variables are pre-setup).

Why am I getting this strange error and how to fix it?

I did wonder if it was a problem with the MS environment.  But even if I run the vcvars32.bat file to setup the MS environment before running make it makes no difference.

I noticed that if I use this:

```
ioapi.obj: ioapi.c
    cl -c ioapi.c
```

Then the error goes away.  But I do need to pass in compiler switches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was make's handling of the /W3 /Od switches.  It seems make thinks /W3 is the start of a file due to the / symbol.  So to prevent this I changed the switches to use - instead of /.  eg -W3 -Od which is acceptable to the MS complier/linker.

So the change in the makefile which was required is:

```
ioapi.obj: ioapi.c
    cl -c -W3 -Od ioapi.c
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me track down what was causing my D9024 error.  I was editing the <AdditionalIncludeDirectories> in my .vcxproj, and forgot to add a ';' at the end of one of the paths I had just added.